# Error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the form in index.erb.html file. (upload controller).
When i call localhost:3000/upload/ an error appeares wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) error

```
    <% form_for :picture, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
 <p>
    <label for="picture_first_name">First name::</label>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, :size => 20 %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="picture_last_name">Last name:</label>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name, :size => 20 %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="picture_city">City:</label>
    <%= form.select :city, Picture::CITIES, {}, :onchange => remote_function(:url => {:action => "update_universities"}, :with => "'picture[city]='+value") %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <%= render :partial => 'universities' %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="picture_picture">Photo::</label>
    <%= form.file_field :picture, :size => 20 %>
 </p>
 <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

So, I have a render function, because i use AJAX to update the second select field.

```
   <label for="picture_university">University:</label>
    <%= form.select :university, [] %>
```

What is the problem with my app? Please help me to fix that!

> ArgumentError in Upload#index
>
> Showing
>   app/views/upload/_universities.html.erb
>   where line #2 raised:
>
> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
>
> Extracted source (around line #2):
>
> 1: University:
>   2: <%= form.select :university, [] %>
>
> Trace of template inclusion:
>   app/views/upload/index.html.erb
>
> RAILS_ROOT: /home/user_admin/myapp
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace |
>   Full Trace
>
> /home/user_admin/myapp/app/views/upload/_universities.html.erb:2:in
>   `form'
>   /home/user_admin/myapp/app/views/upload/_universities.html.erb:2:in`
>   _run_erb_app47views47upload47_universities46html46erb_locals_object_universities'
>   /home/user_admin/myapp/app/views/upload/index.html.erb:15:in
>   `_run_erb_app47views47upload47index46html46erb' /home/user_admin/myapp/app/views/upload/index.html.erb:1:in`
>   _run_erb_app47views47upload47index46html46erb'

Comment: As far as I can tell from your views the variable `form` is not known inside your `universities` view, but this would result in another error.
You should provide the complete error trace for more detail.

Comment: Koraktor, please help.
I've just added the complete error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `form` variable through to your partial, so:

```
<%= render :partial => 'universities', :locals => {:form => form } %>
```

this should make the form object available to your partial.

Comment: Lolindrath, thank u very,very much!!! I'm happy now.
But I still can't understand why I need to do that. I SEE that RAILS framework is very pointed and difficult.

Comment: The reason this happens is because you are moving into a different ruby file which changes your variable scope.

There are a few quirky things you have to deal with in Rails but generally the shear velocity that Rails lets you develop at is staggering.